Line webhook not getting active programatically
i am trying to add webhook to line programatically via channel access token. My code sets the webhook to line, but the webhook does gets enabled.
Below is my code for it:
async function setWebhook(channelAccessToken) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-line-signature": "2e7306a15c5c775341f003d65fe62d72",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${channelAccessToken}`,
    },
  };
  const data = {
    endpoint: `${baseUrl}/line/webhook`
  };
  try {
    const result = await axios.put(
      "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/channel/webhook/endpoint",
      data,
      config
    );
    console.log("result.data ============= ", result.data);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log("tester ========== ", error)
    throw new Error("Error setting webhook: " + error.message);
  }
}

But when i hit the below api, it gives response which shows that webhook is set but not enabled.
const verifyResult = await axios.get(
  "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/channel/webhook/endpoint",
  config
);

Below is the response:
{
    "endpoint": "https://1f29-45-248-162-227.ngrok-free.app/line/webhook",
    "active": false
}

Do anyone have any idea, how to solve it, any small help will be really appreciated !!!
I have tried to pass enable:true while setting up the webhook, but that also didn't worked. Can somebody help?

You have to verify that before use

You have to verify the webhook url after creating.
It can be done in two ways,

Using axios

const response = await axios.post(
    'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/channel/webhook/test',
    {
        endpoint: `${baseUrl}/line/webhook`
    },
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer {CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
);


Using LINE Developers Console, click the webhook URL's Verify button to perform the verification.


LINE Doc for verifying webhook url

Hi @Yuvaraj M, thanks for you response, i have used the first way, i get the following json:
{
"success": true,
"timestamp": "2024-05-24T06:15:38.383331Z",
"statusCode": 200,
"reason": "OK",
"detail": "200"
}
but this does not enable the webhook, and since i want to do it programatically, i can't use the second step.

since it doesn't solves the issue, so i can't accept the answer

else try some methods specified in docs

A wild guess, maybe you did not enable the webhook by clicking Use Webhook see here?:



thanks for your response, as I want to do it programmatically, I can't use it this way.

@Anonymous did you try adding active: "true" to const data ?

yes, bt that also didn't worked.
